# Crashlytics Manifest Merge issue with Instant App Architecture

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I have a multi-feature instant app setup and when I try to view the merged manifest of the application I see the following:

```
Error: Attribute provider#com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider@authorities
value=(com.happyapp.app.crashlyticsinitprovider) from AndroidManifest.xml:14:13-75 is also present
at AndroidManifest.xml:40:87-161 value=(com.happyapp.app.app.crashlyticsinitprovider). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to <provider> element at AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-16:39 to override. app main manifest (this file), line 13
```

I have looked multiple places and have not found any way to fix this. I can follow the suggestion, but the line that is mentioned to fix doesn't exist in the manifest.

This is the installed app manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.happyapp.app" />
```

Comment: Perhaps copy/past your app Manifest xml to see if we can help

Comment: Is that the complete manifest of your app module? from the logs it seems you have a <provider> setup and the crashlytic library is also defining. If you have a <provider> try add what the logs suggest.

Comment: Yes. It is very simple. It is just meant to be a simple manifest that aggregates all of the modules (base + features)

Comment: If I remove crashlytics then everything works.

Comment: check all of your module manifest then and see if any defines <provider> . Also if you can add the crashlytics library as source you may be able to modify the manifest yourself

Comment: I will. I think it is the fabric gradle plugin that is adding the provider.

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague was able to workaround the issue by adding the following element to the installed apk AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
    <provider
        android:name="com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsInitProvider"
        android:authorities="com.happy.happyapp.happyapp.crashlyticsinitprovider"
        tools:replace="android:authorities" />
</application>
```